Logic Apps - Until Loop not recognising Total Pages Value
One particular API does not want to accept the total pages value for the until loop. It keeps going back to the default of 60. I can't seem to figure out why. What I have currently is below.
Until (loop) and within it:
HTTP Request>Parse (Json)>Increment Variable
Within the Until (loop) I have the expression for TotalPages is equal to IncrementPage variable (which is original value 1 and gets incremented by 1).
Expression used to extract total pages: body('Parse_User_Data')?['meta']?['pagination']?['total_pages']
Example json in the Until (loop):
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 11111,
      "display_name": "Tester",
      "title": "Mr"
    },
    
  ],
  "meta": {
    "pagination": {
      "total": 1089,
      "count": 15,
      "per_page": 15,
      "current_page": 1,
      "total_pages": 73,
      "links": {
        "next": "Test.com"
      }
    }
  }
}


Okay, found the fix. I had to remove the default count value. So remove the 60, leaving the column/value empty.
I'm sure we didn't have to do this in the past.
